# license issue in mule when building with junit test cases

Tags: maven, junit, mule

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

When I am building the mule maven project by skipping the `Junit` test cases. The build is success. But when I'm building the same project with Juint test cases build is getting failed with an error message as:

```
Caused by: com.mulesource.licm.impl.InvalidLicenseKeyException: de.schlichtherle.license.NoLicenseInstalledException: 

There is no license certificate installed for MuleSource Enterprise Edition.
at com.mulesource.licm.impl.TrueLicenseHelper.validateLicenseKey(TrueLicenseHelper.java:233).
```

I am just building.please tell me what i have to do to overcome this problem.If i am running the Junit test cases in the mule it is running.when i convert it to maven project and starts building,then i m facing the above issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Enterprise features, you will need a valid license (muleLicenseKey.lic) in the classpath to run tests with Maven.

Comment: I had added .lic file in src/test/resources. Still showing the same error. DO I need to add any configaration to pick licence.lic in pom.xml ?

Comment: You need the muleLicenseKey.lic file that is generated from license.lic. http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+an+Enterprise+License

Answer (score 0):

To run tests outside Studio you should copy the muleLicense.lic from your conf folder into your classpath (i.e. src/test/resources)

Comment: I had added .lic file in src/test/resources. Still showing the same error. DO I need to add any configaration to pick licence.lic in pom.xml ?

Comment: I can confirm that adding the muleLicense.lic into the src/test/resources directory does enable the Mule tests to be run via the Maven command line.

FYI you may had to add xalan.jar to the test scope – I presume that Mule Studio provides a suitable source of XPathAPI within its own runtime environment.

Answer (score -1):

As of Mule version  3.5.2, you no longer need a license file for unit tests running under Maven.

Add a system property argument to the Maven command:

```
mvn clean test -Dmule.testingMode=true
```

This will run tests without requiring a license file.